# How to sort the output to show ascending in dataTable?

Tags: c#

As question how to sort the output to show ascending in dataTable. I want to sort it by start_time in datatable. I'm new to c#.

I have add each of the variable into the dataTable like this

```
dt.Rows.Add(product_name, first_Column, third_Column, run_time, inspected, pass, reject, invalid, yield, start_time, stop_time);
```

And this is where I display the data from dataTable. But How I get the date from that?

```
            foreach(DataRow row1 in dt.Rows)
            {
                //string product = string.Format("{0}",row1.ItemArray[0]); //row1.ItemArray[0];


                var productName = row1.ItemArray[0];
                var firstColumn = row1.ItemArray[1];
                var thirdColumn = row1.ItemArray[2];
                var runTime = row1.ItemArray[3];
                var Inspected = row1.ItemArray[4];
                var Pass = row1.ItemArray[5];
                var Reject = row1.ItemArray[6];
                var Invalid = row1.ItemArray[7];
                var Yield = row1.ItemArray[8];
                var startTime = row1.ItemArray[9];
                var stopTime = row1.ItemArray[10];

                //if (startTime != null || startTime < startDateTemp)

                //string startDateTemp = startTime.ToLongDateString();

                Console.WriteLine();

                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("|{0,5}|{1,5}|{2,5}|{3,5}|{4,5}|{5,5}|{6,5}|{7,5}|{8,5}|{9,5}|{10,5}|"
                    , productName, firstColumn, thirdColumn, runTime, Inspected, Pass, Reject, Invalid, Yield, startTime, stopTime));


                //DateTime maxDate = Convert.ToDateTime(((from DataRow dr in dt.Rows orderby Convert.ToDateTime(dr[9]) descending select dr).FirstOrDefault()[9]));
                //Console.WriteLine(maxDate);

            }
```

Comment: Latest, earliest date of?

Comment: what is the code you have tried? which part of code is not working as you are expecting? and as asked by @G_S what is latest and earliest date???

Comment: sorry for unclear... I change my question already.. I want to sort the result by {9,5}

Comment: You can convert DataTable to DataView. DataView has method to sort data by column name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataTable's Select(string expression, string order) method instead of DataTable.Rows. That is

```
 foreach(DataRow row1 in dt.Select('','start_time ASC'))
 {
    ...
 }
```

Have a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.select?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_DataTable_Select_System_String_System_String_

Comment: I found my date above have some extra words... then I use substring to remove it...then I add in this

DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(start_time, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);  but it show the input string was not a valid date

Comment: I am not sure I understood what you mean but if it says you "input string was not a valid date" then it means "input string was not a valid date". So best way is to check if the input string is valid date or not you can use DateTime.TryParse method: https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2